# php - Get IP from each computer (same network or not)

Tags: php

I am implementing a survey and I want to check if the client has already answered it. Most people answering that survey are using computers from my uni, therefore they all share the same network (eduroam) and by using

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

I always get the same IP... Therefore using it blocks all other users in different computers.
What can I do different? Thank you

Comment: Drop a cookie on their machine?

Comment: Not really surprising : many networking configuration will produce this, for example if your campus network is configured with a central proxy server, you will get that IP addy every time (other scenarios exist).  As @AlexHowansky said, cookie is the way to go here.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I'm already doing such. The thing is you can clear cookies...

Comment: You can also fake your IP by using a VPN or proxy. If you want something foolproof then you'll need to require per-user authentication.

Comment: Send a unique survey ID with the link, as each is completed set flag in DB.  If a user clicks into a survey that has been completed, throw an error and exit/redirect